# Загрузка тхт файл с помощью php в sql

Tags: php, html, sql, база-данных, файлы

нужно загружать данные из тхт файла с помощью пхп в таблицу скл. пример пхп скрипта, который не работает. можете помочь?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","a_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = LOAD DATA INFILE '\\test.txt' INTO TABLE a_db.aa;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `aa`");

echo "<table class='people'>
<tr class='titles'>
<th>aaa</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['aaa'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: А где кавычки у текста запроса?

Comment: $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '\\test.txt' INTO TABLE a_db.aa";
Добавил. Не помогло.

Comment: А исполнять этот запрос не пробовал?

Comment: запрос есть (который `$sql = "LOAD DATA...`, но где он исполняется? вы строку записали и все.

Comment: Извините, не понял что значит "но где он исполняется?". Можете подсказать как это иправит и что добавить?

Comment: $sql = LOAD DATA INFILE '\\test.txt' INTO TABLE a_db.aa;
исправил на
$sql =  mysqli_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '\\test.txt' INTO TABLE a_db.aa(aaa)");
но все равно не работает

Comment: Весь скрипт переделал но все равно не загружается файл.

Comment: `<?php
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'a_db');
$mysql->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '\\test.txt' INTO TABLE a_db.aa(aaa)");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($mysql);
?>`